# XSLT option selector

Tags: xml, xslt

When confronted with XML of

```
<entity1>
    <name>2345</name>
    <type notNull="1" size="normal">select</type>
    <value>D</value>
    <options>
        <option />
        <option>
            <value>A</value>
            <show>Alpha</show>
        </option>
        <option>
            <value>B</value>
            <show>Beta</show>
        </option>
        <option>
            <value>G</value>
            <show>Gamma</show>
        </option>
        <option>
            <value>D</value>
            <show>Delta</show>
            <selected />
        </option>
</entity1>
```

How to extract "Delta" from entity1, maching based on value or " < selected />" tag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the current context node is the `entity1` you can use

```
<xsl:value-of select="options/option[selected]/show" />
```

to find it based on the existence of the `<selected/>` element, or

```
<xsl:value-of select="options/option[value=current()/value]/show"/>
```

to find it based on matching the `<value>` (the `current()` function gives you the current context node, i.e. whatever is `.` at the top-level of the `select` expression, in this case the `entity1`).

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a [variable](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#element-variable), as follows:

```
   <xsl:template match="/entity1">
      <xsl:variable name="selected" select="value"></xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="options/option[value=$selected]/show"/>
   </xsl:template>
```

For bulk lookups, the better alternative is to use a [key](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-key)

```
   <xsl:key name="selected" match="/entity1/options/option" use="value" />

   <xsl:template match="/entity1">
      <xsl:value-of select="key('selected', value)/show"></xsl:value-of>
   </xsl:template>
```